# Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Blender Stack Exchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Motion Tracking. What do the graphs represent and how are they useful?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/motion-tracking-what-do-the-graphs-represent-and-how-are-they-useful)

**Net Score: 15** (Excellent: 15, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What causes odd deformations when using Subsurf?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14196/what-causes-odd-deformations-when-using-subsurf)

**Net Score: 12** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Get list of operators in a menu layout](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13519/get-list-of-operators-in-a-menu-layout)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is it possible to make a modifier with a python addon?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14321/is-it-possible-to-make-python-addon-as-a-modifier)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Calling Python Function from Console](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13835/calling-python-function-from-console)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How do I animate a character with dangling chain](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13916/how-do-i-animate-a-character-with-dangling-chain)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Create HDR map from render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13853/create-hdr-map-from-render)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Create and export bounding boxes for objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14070/create-and-export-bounding-boxes-for-objects)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Moving a Linked Library](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13800/moving-a-linked-library)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Child of Constraint creates strange glitch?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13575/child-of-constraint-creates-strange-glitch)

**Net Score: -8** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 9)

---

Answer (score -1):

When i try to go to the Site Self-Evaluation review queue, then i get this message:

```
You need at least 15 reputation to review site self-evaluation.
```

And when i try to add a comment instead of an answer, then i need 50 reputations.

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges. You need a certain amount of reputation on the site to perform certain tasks.

Comment: I thought of people who do not have enough reputation to answer the self evaluation, but have enough skills to give answers to the list of questions mentioned above...